# How to update winform controls in host project through wcf service?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a Client Solution that is windows forms project with one form and button "Connect" (to wcf service).

Also I have another solution, that consists of wcf library project (for wcf service) and windows forms project (for the host). WCF service implements the simplest method Connect that increases counter and calls callback that notifies client. How can I update form controls in host project through wcf service (Connect method)?

IMonitoringService:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMonitoringServiceCallback))]
public interface IMonitoringService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Connect(string name);
}

public interface IMonitoringServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Notify(string msg);
}
```

MonitoringService:

```
public class MonitoringService : IMonitoringService
{ 
    private int _registeredUsers = 0;

    public void Connect(string name)
    {
        _registeredUsers++;

        // How i should update textBox in Host form here?
        // Something like this: textBox1.Text = name; 

        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMonitoringServiceCallback>();
        callback.Notify(_registeredUsers.ToString());
    }
}
```

Host:

```
public partial class MonitoringListenerForm : Form
{
    private ServiceHost host = null;

    public MonitoringListenerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStartListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (host == null)
        {
            host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MonitoringService));
            host.Open();

            textBox1.Text = "Host started @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnStopListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        host.Close();
        host = null;
        textBox1.Text = "Host closed @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public partial class MonitoringClientForm : Form, IMonitoringServiceCallback
{
    private InstanceContext instanceContext = null;
    private MonitoringServiceClient client = null;

    public MonitoringClientForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Notify(string msg)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Callback: " + msg;
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
        client = new MonitoringServiceClient(instanceContext);

        try
        {
            client.Connect("client1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }         
}
```

Update: For example in Monitoring listener textBox should be displayed client`s name, when client connected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MueTV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbackcontract can be used according to your description. The Callback function will call the client-side code, put the parameters you need to update in textbox into the callback function and pass them to the client for execution. The client-side will update textbox with the parameters passed from the server-side.

Here is my demo. The binding used is wsdualhttpbinding.

```
       public class MonitoringService : IMonitoringService
{
    private  static int _registeredUsers = 0;

    public void Connect(string name)
    {
        _registeredUsers++;
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMonitoringServiceCallback>();
         callback.Notify(_registeredUsers.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is the code of the server. The server-side calls the client-side code through callback and passes a parameter. The client will get the parameter and execute it.

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);
        var client = new MonitoringServiceClient(instanceContext);

        try
        {
            client.Connect("client1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public void Notify(string msg)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Callback: "+msg;
    }
```

This is the client code. The client implements callback.

[image]

This is the result.

```
       public class MonitoringService : IMonitoringService
{
    private  static int _registeredUsers = 0;

    public void Connect(string name)
    {
        _registeredUsers++;
        Console.WriteLine("success");
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMonitoringServiceCallback>();
        callback.Notify("name");
    }
}
```

Modifying parameters in Notify.

[image]

You can update the client-side textbox value by modifying the parameters in Notify.

**UPDATE**

The value of the textbox can be obtained by reflection and then sent to the client-side.

```
      public void Connect(string name)
    {
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMonitoringServiceCallback>();
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        Type type = typeof(Form1);
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo propertyInfo = type.GetField("textBox1");
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox)propertyInfo.GetValue(form);
        callback.Notify(textBox.Text);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I wanted to achieve a little different. I have 2 forms - one for the host and one for the client. The host form has a “Start Listening” button and a text box. Instead of writing the succeess string to the console, I need to write it to a text box on the form in which the host is started.

Comment: You can get the value in textbox through reflection